# Update Access Tabels using Excel tabels

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I got the following problem:

> 1. I imported Excel Files into my Access DB using the normal
>      "functions", but those now **don't allow me** to update the now created
>      Access tables.
> 2. I can only add new `Datasets` using this way and not update the existing
>      ones.

After some research it seems like this is **only possible via VBA or SQL**.

But how would it work? Is there a script i can use do make such an update via a button or such?

Thanks for the help.
Matthias

Comment: How did you imported the excel files, using code(vba), or with design wizard?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't link the Excel file? https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Import-or-link-to-data-in-an-Excel-workbook-a1952878-7c58-47b1-893d-e084913cc958#__link_to_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set up a linked spread sheet to your access table that will allow you to edit the data in both places iirc